# JQuery Mobile - Dynamically Populated Nested List Formatting Issue on Subsequent Access

Tags: jquery, formatting

I am running into an issue with formatting a dynamic list. I believe I am making the correct calls to JQM for it to re-stylize things as it appears correctly on the first access.  If I then go back and try to traverse the list again the list has no formatting.

I have created a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/wsLFs/41/

To get it to break click "Go to Page 2" -> "Add Some Stuff" -> Item 2
Notice at this point things are looking good.  Now click any sub item that was under Item 2 and then go "Go to Page 2" -> Item 2.

Notice that now it doesn't have any list styling.  No right arrows on the items, and no boxes around each style.